# Skip a chosen ratio of cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have tried to:

```
Take item 1 from List A and put it in row 1.
Then put item 2 from List A in row 11.
Then put item 3 from list A in row 21 (etc.)
```

Then I tried to do the same with List B but:

```
Item 1 from List B to row 2.
Item 2 from List B to row 12.
Item 3 from List B to row 22 (etc)
```

How do I tell Excel to fill the cells in this ratio?

Comment: By List A do you mean column A? By List B do you mean column B? What column do you want your output to be in?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it involves inserting a column before both columns A & B

If you insert a column and put 1 in A1 and then the formula `=A1+10` in cell A2 and fill down, you will have your row ratio 1,11,21,31.  Do the same for column B but start with 2 in cell `C1` and enter the formula `=C1+10` in C2 and fill down.

Now that you have the destination row number next to your data, you can use a vlookup to pull the correct data into the correct row.

cell E1 `=iferror(vlookup(Row(),$A$1:$B$20,2,false),"")`

cell F1 `=iferror(vlookup(Row(),$C$1:$D$20,2,false),"")`

or you could combine them in the same column using

`=iferror(vlookup(Row(),$A$1:$B$20,2,false),iferror(vlookup(Row(),$C$1:$D$20,2,false),""))`

[image: Ratio example]